# Fine Uploader Response Error OnComplete In IE 10

Tags: fine-uploader

Manual Uploader Working Fine with All Browser expect IE 10, i am not getting correct Response From the Server it is Showing on onComplete "**No Valid message Received from Loaded iframe For i frame Name 1_97604 cec......**". 
File are uploading into the cloudbees server but not getting correct Response From the server. 
In case of Other browser i am getting Response.success = true, but For IE 10 its undefined, how to handle this error. Please help me Out for this.

Regards 
Yogesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using IE10 if that is the message you are seeing.  Most likely, you are using IE9 or older.  The message you are seeing is logged by the form uploader, which is never used if you are uploading via IE10.  Perhaps you are running IE10 in IE9 or IE8 mode.  Either way, the message indicates that you are working in a cross-origin environment (you have set the `cors.expected` option to true) but are not returning the proper response from your server.  Note that older browsers, such as IE9 and older, utilize form submits, targeting an iframe, to upload files.  In order to access the contents of that cross-origin iframe, the iframe needs to post a message containing the server response to Fine Uploader's window.  This is all very easy to do, all you need to do is return a text/html response from your server that looks something like this:

```
"{\"success\": true, \"uuid\": \"9da17ad5-ad6a-40cd-81b5-226e837db45b\"}<script src=\"http://<YOUR_SERVER_DOMAIN>/iframe.xss.response-<VERSION>.js</script>.js\"></script>"
```

The javascript file mentioned in the script tag is provided in the Fine Uploader released zip file.  It does all of the work for you.  You must return a JSON response before the script tag, as illustrated above, and the response must include the UUID of the associated file.

You should read about cross-origin support either in the [associated blog post](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/31/cors-support-in-3-3/).

Comment: No Ray, i am using IE 10 now my error has been changed to Upload Failure. That time i was using **expected =true** and allowxdr = true in cors but Now i using **expected =false** and allowxdr = true, now its Showing Upload Failure Error but Files are Uploading into The server.

Comment: allowXdr=true has no effect if expected=False.

Comment: Why are you enabling any of the CORS options if you are not working in a cross-origin environment?  If you are working in a cross-origin environment, you NEED to set `expected` to true and return the proper responses, as detailed in the blog post I linked to.

Comment: yes i am using Cross-origin When i set expected = true  it showing  **No Valid message Received from Loaded iframe For i frame Name 1_97604 cec......** in IE 10 Only. when i set it to false then it showing Upload error. With Crome And Firebox inn both case Work Fine.

Comment: That message indicates that you are either not using IE10, or your IE10 is configured in some bizarre way that makes it behave as IE9 or older.  You will never see a message like that if you are using a standard version of IE10 in default mode.

Comment: Thanks Ray For Answering Actually i am working with Salesforce's visualforce Page, in this I have <actionRegion > tag , which is creating problem For IE 10. Now its working Fine When I removed that tag. Thanks once again Ray Nicholus